# Julia: use convolution to compute second derivative?

Tags: julia, derivative

I was trying to compute the second derivative of a function represented in a array. I am using

```
conv(u,[1,-2,1])[2:length(u) - 1]/dx
```

as a way of approximating the second derivative, but it is not accurate enough for my purpose. Does anyone know another method of taking the second derivatives?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to represent your function as an array? Can you use something like `ForwardDiff` or similar?

Comment: There might be an operator you can use in https://github.com/SciML/DiffEqOperators.jl
In particular, search for `CenteredDifference`

Comment: How did you determine that it's not accurate enough? Do you have some reference/ground truth, or an alternative method to compare it with?